# How can I swap position of 2 UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I want to swap the positions of 2 `UIButtons` when a particular button is pressed. Here is my code. Both of them are under the constraints of `Autolayout`

```
 CGRect tempFrame=_flightButton.frame;
    UIViewAutoresizing tempResize=_flightButton.autoresizingMask;
    [_flightButton setFrame:_contactButton.frame];
    [_flightButton setAutoresizingMask:_contactButton.autoresizingMask];

    [_contactButton setFrame:tempFrame];
    [_contactButton setAutoresizingMask:tempResize];
```

Tried this too. To swap constraints. That did not work either

```
NSArray *tempConstraints=_flightButton.constraints;
    [_flightButton removeConstraints:_flightButton.constraints];
    [_flightButton addConstraints:_contactButton.constraints];
    [_contactButton removeConstraints:_contactButton.constraints];
    [_contactButton addConstraints:tempConstraints];
```

Comment: If you are using auto layout then you need to modify the constraints, not change the frame or resizing masks. Create two sets of constraints in your storyboard, one set of which is disabled. When you want to swap the buttons disable one set of constraints and enable the others

Comment: If you're using `Autolayout` try not to set the frames manually, but change `.constant` property of the constraints.

Comment: Can I swap the constraints? like, assign constraints of ButtonOne to ButtonTwo and ViceVersa?

Comment: Yes, you can swap the constraints.

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: You can't swap constraints. `firtstItem` and `secondItem` is not mutable properties. You should remove old and add new. Or change priorities. Personally I prefer way with changing priorities.

Comment: Look the thing is, the app was completed by someone and I am doing a modification to it. the modification involves this swapping and I can't change priorities because there are too many on one button.

Comment: Both buttons have a segue to it. It's not manual. Is there some way i can swap their segues? I can change the appearance of the buttons to make it look swapped

Comment: Create the segues between the ViewControllers instead of between Button->ViewController. On the Swap button click, change the appearance of the Buttons with a fade effect or animation. Set a tag value on the two buttons to indicate which ViewController to move next. Like initially on Button1 set tag =1 and on button2, tag =2. On Swap button click, along with appearance change the tag values.Create a common button click event method, and based on tag value of the sender button, call performSegueWithIdentifier and go to appropriate ViewController.